# Designated initializer warnings when calling another init from initWithCoder:

Tags: ios, objective-c, designated-initializer

I am working on an inherited codebase and trying to resolve the following warnings:

> Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super'
>
> Designated initializer missing a 'super' call to a designated initializer of the super class

The code is:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [self initWithFrame:[CDCUtility getScreenBounds]]; //switching to super breaks
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setArray:[NSMutableArray new]];
        [self setButtonArray:[NSMutableArray new]];
        _graphicEQ = [[CDCEffectsGraphicEQ alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((1024 / 2) - (811 / 2), 60, 860, 255)];
        [self addSubview:_graphicEQ];
        [_graphicEQ setDelegate:self];
        [self addBypassButtonToView];
        [self addFlatButtonToView];
        [self addScrollView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So from what I can make out the developer overrode the superclass `initWithCoder:` (This is a `UIView`) to allow the custom UI to be loaded, and passed in this `initWithFrame:` parameter using custom arguments to create the view.

I have seen some say change the `[self initWithFrame:]`' in `initWithCoder:` to `[super initWithFrame:]` which does resolve the warnings, however it also bypasses calling the features necessary here to load the view correctly.

It works fine as is; I just wanted to cut down all possible warnings, so I wondered if changes can be made to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self designatedInitializer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self designatedInitializer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) designatedInitializer {
    [self setArray:[NSMutableArray new]];
    [self setButtonArray:[NSMutableArray new]];
    _graphicEQ = [[CDCEffectsGraphicEQ alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((1024 / 2) - (811 / 2), 60, 860, 255)];
    [self addSubview:_graphicEQ];
    [_graphicEQ setDelegate:self];
    [self addBypassButtonToView];
    [self addFlatButtonToView];
    [self addScrollView];
}
```

Comment: partially works but i loose things like background colours and some other styling, any idea why? i assume the superclass is now setting frame elements that i dont want